# Rspec Test Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eql(sizes_path)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a Rspec Test im trying to run. It did the test manually and once you click Create Size it definitely goes to sizes_path. Why is it going to root url?

Error is

```
Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eql(sizes_path)

       expected: "/sizes"
            got: "/"

       (compared using eql?)
```

Test is

```
require "rails_helper"
require "when_authenticated.rb"
RSpec.feature "adding size" do

    let(:size01) { FactoryGirl.build :size01 }
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build :user }
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true, password: "Password18") }

    scenario "allow a admin user to add a size" do
    admin_logged_in
        visit new_size_path
        fill_in 'Title', with: 'example'
        click_button 'Create Size'
        expect(current_path).to eql(sizes_path)
        expect(page).to have_content("example")
        expect(page).to have_content("You have created a new size")
    end


    scenario "user can't add size" do
        user_logged_in
        visit sizes_path    
        expect(current_path).to eql(root_path)
    end

    scenario "vistor can't add size" do
        visit sizes_path    
        expect(current_path).to eql(root_path)
    end

end
```

Here is my Create Method in Sizes controller

```
  def create
    @size = Size.new(size_params)
    if @size.save
      redirect_to sizes_path
      flash[:success] = "You have created a new size"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

New View

```
<center><h1>Create A New Size</h1></center>

<div class="container">
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= simple_form_for @size do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :title %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Create Size", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the error occur after click_button in your test (probably this line "expect(current_path).to eql(sizes_path)")? If so, try to take it out and see if it passes.

Comment: @nersoh yes. Once you click the button it redirects to root path

Answer (score 0):

For some reason admin wasn't being created properly. Here is the fix.

```
require "rails_helper"
RSpec.feature "adding size" do

    let(:size01) { FactoryGirl.build :size01 }
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build :user }
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true, password: "Password18" ) }

    def admin_logged_in
      visit login_path
      fill_in 'Email', with: admin.email
      fill_in 'Password', with: admin.password
      click_button 'Log In'
    end

     def user_logged_in
      visit login_path
      fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
      fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
      click_button 'Log In'
    end

    scenario "allow a admin user to add a size" do
    admin_logged_in
        visit new_size_path
        fill_in 'Title', with: 'example'
        click_button('Create Size')
        expect(current_path).to eql(sizes_path)
        expect(page).to have_content("List Of Sizes")
        expect(page).to have_content("You have created a new size")
    end

    scenario "user can't add size" do
        user_logged_in
        visit sizes_path    
        expect(current_path).to eql(root_path)
    end

    scenario "vistor can't add size" do
        visit sizes_path    
        expect(current_path).to eql(root_path)
    end

end
```